# $\phi^*(e^{x+y}dx ∧ dy)$

Tags: calculus, analysis, differential-geometry

Let $ \phi : R^2 → R^2$ be the differentiable application defined by $\phi(u, v) = (2u-v, 3u+2v) =: (x, y) $.
Compute:

$$\phi^*(e^{x+y}dx ∧ dy). $$

I've tried to replace x and y with those given by the problem, but I can't understand how to do it with $\phi^*$.

Comment: Good idea to explain the notation, unless people like me who don't know what the notation means are not going to be able to understand the question.

Comment: @PrimeMover $\phi^*$ is the pull-back operation

Comment: Yeah you're right, stupid of me to have asked. Good job I didn't ask what $\wedge$ means in this context, I'd not have had a clue what that meant either.

Comment: Prime Mover you clearly don't have the background to answer this question. Notation used here is standard and requires no explanation.

Comment: Performing all the steps I get:

$$...= e^{5u}5du ∧ dv.$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We write $x,y$ for the associated coordinate function. Then, the properties of the pullback operation tell us that :
\begin{align}
\phi^*(e^{x+y} d x \wedge dy) &= e^{x \circ \phi + y \circ \phi} d (x \circ \phi) \wedge d (y\circ \phi)
\end{align}

Plugging in $x\circ \phi = 2u - v$ and $y \circ \phi = 3u+ v$, you should be able to finish the calculation.

Comment: in case I have a $+$ instead of $∧$ what reasoning should I do?

Comment: The same exact calculation would do : $\phi^*$ is compatible with the addition and wedge product of differential forms (the latter includes the multiplication of a form by a scalar function)